# Google Analytics 4 (GA4): User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. Error 403

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-reporting

Tengo un problema que no consigo sortear. Estoy haciendo algo mal o le falta algo a mi código pero no logro ver el fallo. Trataré de exponer el problema.

Estoy trabajando con Google Analytics versión 4, he creado una propiedad (supongamos que su id sea 999999999).
Esta propiedad tiene un flujo de datos (supongamos que tenga id 5555555555 e id de medición G-N1XX2T3SS4).
También he creado una cuenta de servicio con ID único 111222333444555666777 y a cuyo email "mailserviceaccount@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com", he otorgado acceso en "Gestión de accesos a la propiedad".
En Visual Studio he creado un proyecto web en .Net con C# MVC cuyo código debería permitirme obtener las métricas registradas en la cuenta de Google Analytics y mostrarlas cómo gráficas en una vista.

He generado una clave de cuenta de servicio y he descargado y añadido al proyecto un JSON similar al siguiente (los datos no son los reales):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myprojectname",
  "private_key_id": "8922c8922b892224adb8922f8922e489228922",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxFVEpv4QOTO5LxOaFky9Js8kke5UVkRIdp\nKfK6S7fDmBdqOa9lkhP9yvOkdHiblzcyvZ58vcq3hQKBgQDddwneNU3YsUlXbmWY\nvOJM/aZNziHwZWzNjjLJp3vzvKdsrUJs+FcLLfDcSJ8Uzw8RTkrkhfGh0sKyEjAH\n7hGTVizTXWZkp3O2UCUlDnNOI9bMYaMlbGYFZirQXne6h0f23Q8hrSUfh94XFVEpv4QOTO5LxOaFky9Js8kke5UVkRIdp\nKfK6S7fDmBdqOa9lkhP9yvOkdHiblzcyvZ58vcq3hQKBgQDddwneNU3YsUlXbmWY\nvOJM/aZNziHwZWzNjjLJp3vzvKdsrUJs+FcLLfDcSJ8Uzw8RTkrkhfGh0sKyEjAH\n7hGTVizTXWZkp3O2UCUlDnNOI9bMYaMlbGYFZirQXne6h0f23Q8hrSUfh94X\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "mailserviceaccount@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "111222333444555666777",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mailserviceaccount%40myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

En mi aplicación web he creado un controlador que tiene el siguiente código:

```
//------- CONTROLLER --------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplicationPruebas.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Analytics()
        {
            //1. Creo el objeto credenciales
            var appDataFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/JsonKey");
            var keyFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolderPath, "clave_cuenta_servicio.json");
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keyFilePath)
                              .CreateScoped(AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly);

            //2. Objeto de servicio de informes de Analytics utilizando el objeto de credenciales
            var service = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "myprojectname"
            });

            //3. Solicitud de informe utilizando el ID de la propiedad de Google Analytics, el ID del flujo de datos y el ID de medición.
            var request = new GetReportsRequest()
            {
                ReportRequests = new[] {
                    new ReportRequest(){
                        ViewId = "999999999",
                        DateRanges = new[] { new DateRange { StartDate = "7daysAgo", EndDate = "today" } },
                        Metrics = new[] { new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions" } },
                        Dimensions = new[] { new Dimension { Name = "ga:date" } },
                        PageSize = 10
                    }
                }
            };

            //4. Ejecuto la solicitud de informe utilizando el objeto de servicio de informes de Analytics creado anteriormente
            try
            {
                var response = service.Reports.BatchGet(request).Execute();
                //5. Proceso los resultados de la solicitud de informe y los convierto en datos que puedan ser utilizados para mostrar gráficas
                
                var data = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
                foreach (var row in response.Reports[0].Data.Rows)
                {
                    data.Add(Tuple.Create(row.Dimensions[0], int.Parse(row.Metrics[0].Values[0])));
                }

                ViewBag.Labels = data.Select(d => d.Item1).ToArray();
                ViewBag.Data = data.Select(d => d.Item2).ToArray();

                ViewBag.Message = "My Analytics page.";
                return View();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                return View();
            }

            
        }

    }
}
```

Y la vista en la cual pretendo mostrar los datos es la siguiente:

```
//------- VIEW --------

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Analytics";
    var errorMsg = ViewBag.ErrorMessage;
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>This is the Analytics page... may be...</p>

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
            {
<p><span class="fw-bold text-danger">ERROR: </span> @errorMsg</p>
            }


<script>
    if (document.getElementById('myChart') !== null){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Labels)),
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My Analytics Data',
                    data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data)),
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

El problema es que cuando trato de ejecutar el código, en la línea dónde se trata de ejecutar

```
var response = service.Reports.BatchGet(request).Execute();
```

el código arroja el mensaje de error: "The service analyticsreporting has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Ampliando la información del error recibido, resulta lo siguiente:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

He probado muchas de las soluciones indicadas en la red y he revisado decenas de veces los permisos y todos parecen correctos pero no consigo pasar más allá del error que indico.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con esto por favor?

¡Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras darle diferentes vueltas, he encontrado el fallo: estaba utilizando una API que no era la correcta para obtener los datos de GA4.

Yo estaba usando `Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4` mientras la correcta es `Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta`.

Una vez realizado el cambio,y adaptado el código a la nueva API, todo funciona como es debido.

Dejo el código del controlador con los cambios por si puede ser de utilidad a alguien (el resto queda prácticamente igual):

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebApplicationPruebas.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Analytics()
        {
            string propertyId = "999999999";

            //1. Creamos el objeto credenciales
            var appDataFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/JsonKey");
            var keyFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolderPath, "clave_cuenta_servicio.json");
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keyFilePath);

            var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
            {
                Credential = credential              
            }.Build();

            // Initialize request argument(s)
            BatchRunReportsRequest requests = new BatchRunReportsRequest
            {
                Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
                Requests =
                { new RunReportRequest
                    {
                        Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
                        Dimensions = {
                        new Dimension { Name = "date" },
                        },
                        Metrics = {
                        new Metric { Expression = "sessions", Name = "_Sessions" },
                        },
                        DateRanges = { new DateRange { 
                            StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") }, 
                        },
                    },
                    new RunReportRequest
                    {
                        Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
                        Dimensions = {
                        new Dimension { Name = "month" }, 
                        },
                        Metrics = {
                        new Metric { Expression = "screenPageViews", Name = "_ScreenPageViews" },
                        },
                        DateRanges = { new DateRange { 
                            StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") },
                        },
                    }
                }
            };
            try { 
                // Make the request
                var responses = client.BatchRunReports(requests);

                var data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
                foreach (var report in responses.Reports)
                {
                    foreach (var row in report.Rows)
                    {
                        data.Add(Tuple.Create(row.DimensionValues[0].Value, row.MetricValues[0].Value));
                    }
                }

                ViewBag.Labels = data.Select(d => d.Item1).ToArray();
                ViewBag.Data = data.Select(d => d.Item2).ToArray();

                ViewBag.Message = "My Analytics page.";

                return View();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo.